# Why is my code's 'e' not defined?

Tags: javascript, html

I want to comment on the user's the input.In my code e is a function and in onclick attribute we write a function so where am wrong please please help.

```
<form>
  What color do you prefer?<br>
  <input type="radio" id="userInput" >Red<br>
  <input type="radio" id="userInputs" >Blue
</form>

<button onclick="e()">far</button>

<script>
var Input = document.getElementById("userInputss"); 
document.write(userInputs);
Function e(){
if(userInputss===userInput){
document.write("good");}
else if(Input===userInputs){
document.write("go");}
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: make it function e()

Comment: There are multiples errors: userInputss does not exists. Close the input element. Function.

Comment: This is how my real code is ,that was sent by mistaken.

Comment: What is you trying to do?  function e doesn't makes sense.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not are clean to me what you are trying to do in `e` function, but I build this example for help you:

```js
var red = document.getElementById("colorRed")
  , blue = document.getElementById("colorBlue"); 

//document.write(red);

function e(){
  if(blue.checked == true){
    document.write("You prefer Blue");
  } else if (red.checked == true){
    document.write("You prefer Red");  
  } else {
    document.write("You prefer nothing");  
  }
}
```

```html
<form>
  What color do you prefer?<br>
  <input type="radio" id="colorRed" >Red</input>
  <input type="radio" id="colorBlue" >Blue</input>
</form>

<button onclick="e()">far</button>
```

Comment: Can we make such type function happen 2 times??

Comment: Depends of logic, If it in inside a loop, yes, or you call as recursive mode, yes too

Comment: When the user clicks both of them it must be displaying  _You prefer nothing_ but it shows _You prefer Blue_.Why??

Comment: Because there doesn't has some condition to catch in case of both. You can make a If condition If both as checked or set the same name to both option..this way the user Will can select only one checkbox

Comment: So can't just else mean it??

Answer (score 0):

Because your code is not in `<script>` and `function` should be lowercase. Try this:

```
<form>
  What color do you prefer?<br>
  <input type="radio" id="userInput" >Red<br>
  <input type="radio" id="userInputs" >Blue
</form>

<button onclick="e()">far</button>

<script>
var Input = document.getElementById("userInputs"); 
document.write(userInputs);

function e(){
  console.log("Click");
  /* I'm not sure what that is supposed to do:
  if(userInputs===userInput){
    document.write("good");
  } else if(Input===userInputs){
    document.write("go");
  }*/
}

</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Look in the console (F12 -> console) to see the click.